# How can I pass variables back and forth between two classes in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing a GUI that imports and plots data (csv file). Data are initially imported in the `TabWidget()` class using `getfile()` and `on_pushButtonLoad_clicked()` and passed to the `FirstTab()` class, where `MRChart()` is plotted in the `infrastructure()` widget. To achieve this, I created the `firstTab` instance in `TabWidget()` (apologies if my terminology is incorrect here).

The end goal is to update the plot based on the numerical range selected on a rangeslider. Firstly, I want to pass the value of `slider1` to `FirstTab()` and I should be able to manage from there. To do this, I have attempted to create the `tabwidget` instance in `FirstTab()`. However, I get the following: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded". I presume this is due to each class having an instance of itself contained in the other.

Any help appreciated.

Code:

```
class TabWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.firstTab = FirstTab(self.data)
        self.showMaximized()

        # create Header 
        FilterLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        FilterLayout.addWidget(self.createHeader1a(), 1) 
        FilterLayout.addWidget(self.createHeader2a(), 4)

        # create Tab
        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(self.firstTab, "Tab 1")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(FilterLayout)
        vbox.addWidget(tabwidget)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def createHeader1a(self):  #Import 
        HeaderBox = QGroupBox("Import Data")

        inputfilebtn = QPushButton("Import")
        inputfilebtn.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        # importrow1
        importrow1layout = QHBoxLayout()
        importrow1layout.addWidget(inputfilebtn)

        HeaderLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        HeaderLayout.addLayout(importrow1layout)
        HeaderBox.setLayout(HeaderLayout)
        HeaderBox.setFlat(True)

        return HeaderBox

    def createHeader2a(self): #Filter

        HeaderBox = QGroupBox("Filter Data")

        rightlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        # range slider bar to filter column data for plotting
        label4 = QLabel(self)
        label4.setText("Filter range:")
        rightlayout.addWidget(label4)
        self.slider1 = QLabeledRangeSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider1.setRange(5, 500)
        self.slider1.setValue((150, 300))
        rightlayout.addWidget(self.slider1)

        HeaderBox.setLayout(rightlayout)
        HeaderBox.setFlat(True)  #

        return HeaderBox

    #import and return file
    def getfile(self):
        option = QFileDialog.Options()
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                                            'c:\\', "CSV files (*.csv)", options=option)
        return pd.read_csv(fname[0])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        importedfile = self.getfile()
        if importedfile is None:
            return
        self.firstTab.MRChart(importedfile)

        global database
        database = importedfile

    def getslider1value(self):
        return self.slider1.value


class FirstTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(FirstTab, self).__init__() 
        self.data = data
        self.tabwidget = TabWidget(self.data)# issue here. Attempting to # access TabWidget class

        # Grid layout of entire tab
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.infrastructure(self.data), 3, 0)
        layout.setRowStretch(4, 3)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def MRChart(self, importedfile):  # pie chart
        if self.radioButton1.isChecked():
            fig = go.Pie(labels=importedfile[self.radioButton1.label])
        elif self.radioButton2.isChecked():
            fig = go.Pie(labels=importedfile[self.radioButton2.label])

        layout = go.Layout(autosize=True, legend=dict(orientation="h", xanchor='center', x=0.5))
        fig = go.Figure(data=fig, layout=layout)
        fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0))
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))

    def infrastructure(self, importedfile):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Plot")
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)

        right = QVBoxLayout()

        # Change/update plot (MRChart) depending on what Radio button is selected
        self.radioButton1 = QRadioButton("Label 1")
        self.radioButton1.label = "Column_label_1"
        self.radioButton1.toggled.connect(lambda: self.MRChart(database))
        right.addWidget(self.radioButton1)

        self.radioButton2 = QRadioButton("Label 2")
        self.radioButton2.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton2.label = "Column_label_2"
        self.radioButton2.toggled.connect(lambda: self.MRChart(database))
        right.addWidget(self.radioButton2)

        middleright = QHBoxLayout()
        middleright.addWidget(self.browser)
        middleright.addLayout(right)
        groupBox.setLayout(middleright)
        groupBox.setFlat(True)

        print(self.tabwidget.getslider1value())# attempting to print slider value here

        return groupBox

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabwidget = TabWidget(data=None)
    tabwidget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Note that you missed the `if fname` in `getfile`, which would make the `if importedfile is None:` pointless. Please read more carefully my answer to your previous question. Also: 1. don't use globals; 2. you're missing the parentheses of `self.slider1.value` in `getslider1value`; 3. avoid using capitalized names for variables; 4. separate functions that are called just once (like `createHeader1a`) and also create instance attributes are almost always pointless and make your code unnecessarily convoluted; just use code blocks separated by blank lines.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful comments. I actually never spotted ```if fname``` so have added that now. In relation to global variables - This was my solution to allow ```MRChart``` change/update depending on whether ```radioButton1``` or ```radioButton2``` was selected without having to call ```on_pushButtonLoad_clicked``` and ```getfile``` each time. I have now saved the importedfile as ```self.importedfile``` and called it in ```FirstTab``` from ```self.tabwidget.importedfile```. Until next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion error is clear: `TabWidget` tries to create `FirstTab`, but there you're trying to create *another* `TabWidget`, which will create a further `FirstTab` and so on.

If you want to keep reference between objects, you must pass references, not create new instances (see the note below).

Also, since `FirstTab` calls `infrastructure` in the `__init__`, at that point the slider in the parent widget has not been created yet.

You must move the creation of `FirstTab` *after* the slider is created, and pass the reference in the constructor.

```
class TabWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.showMaximized()

        # create Header 
        FilterLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        FilterLayout.addWidget(self.createHeader1a(), 1) 
        FilterLayout.addWidget(self.createHeader2a(), 4)

        self.firstTab = FirstTab(self) # <- pass the reference of the parent
        # ...

class FirstTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, tabwidget):
        super(FirstTab, self).__init__() 
        self.tabwidget = tabwidget
        self.data = tabwidget.data
        # ...
```

<sup>Note that this is the *same* problem you had in your previous question. I strongly suggest you to review the basics of classes and instances and OOP in general, as knowledge and comprehension of those aspects cannot be ignored.</sup>

Comment: Much appreciated once again @musicamante! I haven't been working with python/PyQt5 long so apologies for the repeat errors. I definitely think I could do with focusing more on what exactly each line of code is doing. I come from a MATLAB background so the transition has been somewhat challenging where I have been learning python on a project by project basis. I will go back and learn the basics to help save me (you!) future headaches!

Comment: @Philip well, I've never used MATLAB, but I've read a lot of criticism about its concepts (from the programming perspective) that often lead its users to a great deal of confusion when switching to other languages that are more robust and consistent, and you're not the first I've encountered facing these problems, so you have my sympathy... Good luck ;-)